# Watir can't clear IE security warning

Tags: testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver to drive IE to test a website using a SSL certificate for another website. (the production version of same website)

When I visit my site, I get a page that looks like this (Since the security certificate is bad)
 [image: http://www.zeus.com/sites/default/files/media/warning2.png]

The watir documentation has a workaround for this http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Security+Alerts 
    my_browser.link(:id, "overridelink").click

When I try to run this in the ruby console, I get an error.

```
irb(main):050:0> b.link(:id, "overridelink").click
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedJavascriptError: Unable to find element with xpath == .//a[@id='overridelink']
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:45:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:54:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:54:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:35:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:410:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:388:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:356:in `find_element_by'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:41:in `find_element'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.5/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:86:in `find_first_by_multiple'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.5/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:33:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.5/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:263:in `locate'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.5/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:245:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.5/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:65:in `click'
        from (irb):50
        from :0irb(main):051:0>
```

When you look at the html for the error page, the continue link is definitely there.

```
<tr>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
<td id="continueToSiteAlign" align="left" valign="middle">
    <h4 id="continueToSite">
        <img src="red_shield.png" ID="ImgOverride" border="0" alt="Not recommended icon" class="actionIcon"><A href='' ID="overridelink" NAME="overridelink" >Continue to this website (not recommended).</A>
    </h4>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Is that page being displayed in the main browser instance, or is it popping up a new window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to avoid this automatically as far as I know with Watir-WebDriver.

The solution is to make sure IE doesn't care about this error:

1. Tools and select Internet Options
2. Select the Advanced tab
3. Scroll down and uncheck Warn about certificate address mismatch

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the right page to see how watir-webdriver works with certificates: http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-certificates/

Unfortunately, I do not see anything about IE browser.

**Update**: Alister said "I believe you manually need to add the certificate to trusted root" https://twitter.com/#!/alisterscott/status/124047931945922561

Comment: This is the approach I use, it simulates what a user would see on your production site where the certificate would be genuine and not trigger an invalid cert screen.   Add it to the root cert in your test environments and you are done.   also that way if you ever need to run your scripts against production, they work.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this that I use is to use autoit to tab into the 'continue to website', saves having to add to website all the time

```
    autoit=WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')
    i=1
    while i < 11 
        autoit.Send("{Tab}")
        i+=1
    end

    autoit.Send("{Enter}")
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works on my IE10, it clicks "overridelink" perfectly.

```
browser.goto("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()")
```